# alter object tag update mechanism

Tags: html, html-object

```
<object id="obj" classid="clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93" 
    width="1" height="1" name="....." align="middle"
    codebase="http://java.sun.com/update/1.6.0/jinstall-6u31-windows-i586.cab">
    <param name="code" value ="....." ><param name="archive" value="....." ><param name="name" value="....." >
    <param name="type" value="application/x-java-applet;version=1.5"><param name="scriptable" value="true"> 
    <param name="mayscript" value="yes">
</object>
```

When I use this object tag and Java update is available, it shows a prompt but after selecting option to "Update", it redirects my page to the actual update page. Is there a way to specify to open update page in new window or tab instead of redirecting the current page?